# COPY target/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /test.jar COPY failed cannot find file Docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-build

I'm trying Docker for the first time in a Spring Boot project and I'm trying to make the command `docker build -t javademo:v1.3   .` work. I don't know where the jar file is, in the Dockerfile I've specified this:

```
FROM openjdk:8-windowsservercore

LABEL maintainer="Marina"

COPY target/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /test.jar
EXPOSE 8080:8080

CMD ["java", "-jar", "test.jar"]
```

Because my project name is "test". The problem is that I can't find the test.jar, even if I Maven-build the project. How is this supposed to work? What am I missing?

Comment: can you `ls -l *.* |grep test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` in your dir an confirm that the file is there?

Comment: @JoshBeauregard the file is not found

Comment: if its not there there then your going to have a problem COPYing it it in.

Try running `mvn install |grep "Building jar:"` to verify the location of the build